# achartengine fill out side in linechart

Tags: android, achartengine

I have a problem with fill out side in linechart below. Here is a demo that i have draw. How can i  remove the area in red block.
[image]

```
    XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    renderers.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
    renderer.setLineWidth(2f);
    renderer.setPointStrokeWidth(7f);
    renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    FillOutsideLine below = new FillOutsideLine(FillOutsideLine.Type.BELOW);
    renderer.addFillOutsideLine(below);
```

Comment: I get the answer. use FillOutsideLine.Type.BOUND_ALL